# Excel VBA Filter Copy and Paste under Last used row on seperate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro to filter the results however I would like to automatically copy and paste the filtered results ($A:$M) to sheet "Filter" under the last used row.

Also sometimes the filter will have no results so need something to combat that.

```
Sub FilterResults()

    Sheets("RESULTS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$1006001").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$1006001").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<=15" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Any Help would be appreciated as I'm new to VBA.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Dim targetSht As Worksheet
Set targetSht = Worksheets("Filter")

With Sheets("RESULTS").Range("$A$1:$M$1006001")
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<=15", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSht.Cells(targetSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = false ' remove filtering
End With
```

if you want to keep pasting headers then change

```
.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ...
```

to

```
.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ...
```

---

an enhancement of what above (explanations in comments) is the following:

```
Sub FilterResults()

        Dim targetSht As Worksheet
        Set targetSht = Worksheets("Filter")

        With Sheets("RESULTS") 'reference source sheet
            With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column A to M from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell. this reduces the handled cells and then computational effort
                .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">0"
                .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<=15"
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=targetSht.Cells(targetSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' copy filtered cells skipping headers and paste them to "target" sheet starting from its column A first empty cell
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = false ' remove filtering
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see yours

Comment: @QHarr, I didn't even see yours.... We were typing almost at the same time. It happens... with you!

Comment: Thank you. @DisplayName

Comment: Thank you. @QHarr